# Solution to jquery slideToggle flickering when fired?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, flicker

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4jw2rhpz/1/

Everything goes smoothly when page hasn't been scrolled, but not when page has been scrolled a bit. I'm getting the dreaded flicker right when the scrollTop fires. I've been adding delays, changing CSS, adding/removing from the script, and editing animation values but the flicker is haunting me.

```
$('.thumbs').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300, 'swing');
    $('#displayBox').children().delay(300).slideUp('slow');
    var idVar = this.id;
    $('.' + idVar).slideToggle('slow');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $('#displayBox').children().slideUp('slow');
    $('.splash').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Anyone know a solution? I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: How does one reproduce the issue in the fiddle you have provided?

Comment: I'm getting a flicker in Chrome and FF when scrolling down and clicking a thumb image.

Comment: Removing the slideToggle, I see the flicker is in the scrollTop function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Delete post if necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/4jw2rhpz/2/

```
$('.thumbs').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
...
});
```

Comment: Nice. Just approve your own answer.